# HTACCESS issues with multiple redirects

Tags: htaccess, .htaccess

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to re-direct multiple portions of a site to the https:// version.

What I have so far does work, it just randomly throws in an extra '?' sometimes?

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# https: redirect to safe CP url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

# https: redirect to safe Product url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /product/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

# https: redirect to safe Checkout url
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /checkout/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

# Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>
```

This does work, partially. Like I said, sometimes when a re-drecit happens an extra '?' is thrown in and I can't seem to figure out why.

So if I go to

> http://www.mysite.com/product/some-product

for example, it will re-direct to

> https://www.mysite.com/?/product/some-product

If any additional info is needed let  me know! And thanks for any input in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1):

On line 11, change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And see if that works. According to https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html, you only need to use your entry for forced query strings on hosts such as GoDaddy. However, if that's the case, you may be stuck with it.

Comment: I did try that and unfortunately it didn't work.